# How to disable auto update when jqGrid edited?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to use form editing on jqgrid. When the data is changed, data is sent to the web server an automatically. I don't won't to send edited data to server. Just edit data on html tag value? Any idea? Can you guys put some working example?

Thank you for every advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form editing not support only local editing now. I suggested Tony (the developer of jqGrid) to implement this in the next release of jqGrid (see http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/support-of-editurl-clientarray-local-editing-for-the-form-editing/). We can hope that this feature will be implemented in the future.

Currently you can use only inline editing or cell editing together with the `datatype: 'local'` and `editurl: 'clientArray'`. As an example see http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClientsideEditing4.htm. To go in the edit mode use double click. To conform editing (to save editing results locally) use Enter key.

Comment: You welcome! I personally prefer last time generally to use inline editing instead of form editing, because users find this method more intuitive.